# Bash Script: write all but first three lines of stdin to file

Tags: bash, output-redirect

I am writing a bash script, which at one point uses `nslookup` to resolve some names in a loop. It's output looks something like this:

```
Server:         127.0.0.1
Address:        127.0.0.1#53

Non-authoritative answer:
Name:   example.org
Address: 93.184.216.34
```

I'd like to remove the first three lines, without having to write the output to a file first. I tried using `tail`, but couldn't get it to read from the STDIN.

```
nslookup "${name}" \
    | tail +2 -
```

This tries to read `+2` as a file: `tail: cannot open ‘+2’ for reading: No such file or directory`

How can I pipe the output of nslookup to remove the first three lines, to write all of it to a file later, like this:

```
while read name; do
    nslookup "${name}" \
        | remove-three-lines \
        >> file.out
done <"${nameFile}"
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To start output from 4th line onwards (ignoring first 3 lines):

```
nslookup "${name}" | tail -n +4
```

Or awk:

```
nslookup "${name}" | awk 'NR>3'
```

Or sed:

```
nslookup "${name}" | sed '1,3d'
```

Comment: I have the entire `while` loop in a function which i call like `doStuff > "${outputFile}"` all the `printf` statements in the function are printed into the outputFile but the lines i pipe from `nslookup` into `tail` are printed to stdout, do you know why?

Comment: @CelestialDragonofOsiris: Try: `nslookup "${name}" |& tail -n +4 > "${outputFile}"` as output might be coming from `stderr`

Comment: A complete answer, if a bit dry... I wrote a `sed` answer, that I don't see any reason to post now, that is complementary to yours: `command| sed -n '4,$p'` ... I have to recognize that your answer expresses OP's intent in a more straightforward manner...

Answer (score 0):

What about this:

```
while read name; do
    echo $(nslookup "${name}" | tail -2) >> file.out
done <"${nameFile}"
```

Comment: What is the reason to echo all of it again, shouldn't redirecting tail's output already be enough?

Comment: The lookup and tail are in a subshell in order to get the stdin correct, then the output from that subshell is echoed and redirected to a file.